# Why do we use ΔxΔp≥ℏ instead of ΔxΔp≥ℏ/2 to calculate the minimum uncertainty in momentum?

Tags: momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I came across a question in which we were asked to calculate the minimum uncertainty in the momentum of a particle. The solution showed that the min. uncertainty is found using the formula ΔxΔp≥ℏ instead of ΔxΔp≥ℏ/2. Why do we use this specific formula here?

Comment: Heisenberg's uncertainty principle states that $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\left| \left[ \hat{x}, \hat{p} \right] \right|}{2} = \frac{\hbar}{2}$. Where did you find that formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just because it's only a factor of 2. Same order of magnitude. Using the uncertainty principle for a question like this is usually just meant to be an estimate/ball park, so when you do the proper calculation you know if your final answer makes sense.